# Is it possible to execute an application within an Adobe AIR Desktop Installer for Windows?

Tags: windows, air, installation, windows-installer

I would like to run one or more applications after a successful AIR desktop application install in Microsoft Windows. Is this possible without wrapping the installer with other technology like MSI/InnoSetup/NSIS?